# custom taxonomy meta box doesn't show in the WordPress admin menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a new custom taxonomy in WordPress `functions.php` file but when I want to add new post or edit one I cannot found my custom taxonomy meta box in the right side of the admin menu

my `functions.php` code for custom taxonomy:

```
function create_business_taxonomy() {
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Businesses', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Business', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Businesses' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Businesses' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Business' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Business:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Business' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Business' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Business' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Business Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Business' ),
  );    
 
  register_taxonomy('business-type',array('post'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'business-type' => 'topic' ),
  ));
  
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_business_taxonomy', 0 );
```

but I can't find in where I marked in the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Did I forget or missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set 'show_in_rest' => true. ( (boolean) (optional) Whether to include the taxonomy in the REST API. You will need to set this to true in order to use the taxonomy in your gutenberg metablock. ). So your code will be like this:

```
function create_business_taxonomy() {
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Businesses', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Business', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Businesses' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Businesses' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Business' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Business:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Business' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Business' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Business' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Business Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Business' ),
  );    
 
  register_taxonomy('business-type',array('post'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'business-type' => 'topic' ),
  ));
  
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_business_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter posts using URL??? 
I try this URL to filter my posts like this `http://localhost/myproject/blog/?business-type=21` but nothing returned

Comment: use term slug instead of id like this: http://localhost/myproject/blog/?business-type=your_term_slug _here. Also save the permalink settings from Settings->permalinks( just save the permalink settings, nothing need to change )